# MyPy Decorator that changes output with generics

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to write a decorator in python that allows any input but change the output as enforced by MyPy. This is as close as I've gotten:

```
Output = TypeVar('Output', bound=pydantic.BaseModel)

class Spec(Generic[Output]):
    # implementation

def my_decorator(f: Callable[..., Spec[Output]]) -> Callable[..., Output]:
    # implementation
```

This lets define a method:

```
@my_decorator
def my_method(arg1: str, arg2: int) -> Spec[SomeType]:
    # Implementation
```

MyPy then lets me call this method and it expects `SomeType` as the output instead of `Spec[SomeType]`. This is perfect! The piece I'm missing is how to get it to still expect the same input arguments (preferably any arguments including no arguments).

I also know that if I keep the output the same, I can define a TypeVar for the function like so to hold the input constant:

```
FuncT = TypeVar('FuncT', bound=Callable[..., Any])
def other_decorator(f: FuncT) -> FuncT:
    # implementation
```

How can I get MyPy to enforce that the decorator method returns a function that take the same input but different generic output?

Comment: What? What do you mean you are "writing in MyPy"? You mean *Python*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, sorry, not sure exactly about the terminology. I updated it to hopefully be clearer. The language is clearly Python but I want MyPy to enforce the typing as described in the post.

Comment: Anyway, expressing decorators that change the function signature was, last time I checked, not supported. See this relevant github issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3157 Perhaps there are things that have been released recently, or that are upcoming, the Python typing system is actively being developed

Comment: This is the relevant PEP for Python 3.10: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/.